# how to make a checkbox apply to another table in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I have two tables that store content (2 separate models: microposts and threads)

They are very similar except the names

```
create_table "microposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.boolean  "review",          :default => false
  end

create_table "threads", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
  end
```

This is what I have in view

```
<%= form_for @micropost, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @micropost %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => 5, :rows => 5, :placeholder => "This field is required" %>
  </div>
    <label for="a"><%= label_tag(:micropost_review, "Does this need review?") %><%= f.check_box :review %></label></div>
 <br><br>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do is, instead of the checkbox (label_tag) updating the review attribute, I would like to change the form_for into threads. Instead of populating the microposts table, I want it to populate the threads table if the checkbox is checked prior to submit. What is the best way to update the view above to do this?
Thanks

Comment: **This may blow up in your face.** `Thread` is a [reserved word in Rails](http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/).

Answer (score 0):

This can (and should) be easily done in the MicropostsController, rather than a View. Assuming this is supposed to create a new Micropost or Thread:

```
def create
  if params[:micropost][:review]
    params[:micropost].delete :review
    @thread = Thread.create!(params[:micropost])
  else
    @micropost = Micropost.create!(params[:micropost])
  end
 end
```

Note that it is important to avoid passing extra attributes to create! or it will fail.

Also, don't use Thread as it is a reserved word and could have some very "interesting" consequences...

Comment: Goes in `MicropostController` since the form is posting there.

Comment: Also, heed my warning about `Thread` being a reserved word in Rails. You must change the names of this model and it's database table.